# Progress bar dialog while method are not finished

Tags: android

I need to show simple progress bar dialog while some method not finish.

I Try to call it like

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "", "Please wait");
SyncCity()
SyncStreet()
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

But than app is blocked while method not finish,after that i get progress dialog,and in next second dissapear, sometimes i not See it at all.

All calling is going on button click...
Where is catch?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're blocking the UI thread. Try using AsyncTask, like this:

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "", "Please wait");
        }

        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            SyncCity()
            SyncStreet()
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: I just find that i need change new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{ with new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){ but answer is greate,thank you very mutch

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AsyncTask to do such processes. You shouldn't do any process in the UI thread.

Here is a good example on how to use AsyncTask:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html